# Java ActionListener error: incompatible types

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm having some trouble setting up an ActionListener on a JButton, here is the code...

```
package pipes;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PipesUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Main main = new Main();

    JButton addPipeButton = new JButton("Add Pipe");

    public PipesUI(){
        addUI();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void addUI(){
        addPipeButton.addActionListener(this);
    }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      if (e.getSource()==addPipeButton)
          main.addPipe();
       else
          ;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PipesUI pipesUI = new PipesUI(); //  create an instance of the menu
        pipesUI.setSize(500,500);
        pipesUI.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The error is on the line
addPipeButton.addActionListener(this);

The (this) it doesn't seem to like, the error says 'incompatible types: PipesUI cannot be converted to ActionListener'

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: What is `this`? What type is that reference?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't really know... This is my first time using actionlisteners and ive seen "this" written in those brackets before so i just used them, what should go in the brackets?

Comment: No button appears on my JFrame either, what is causing that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You created your `actionPerformed` method, but you didn't declare your class as an `ActionListener`.  Implement that interface:

```
public class PipesUI extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener {
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the error, but my button is still not showing on the JFrame, why is this?

Comment: I don't see where you added the `JButton` to your `JFrame`.  [Add it.](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/41873-basic-jframe-with-a-basic-jbutton/)

Answer (score 3):

```
addPipeButton.addActionListener(this);
```

Within an instance method or a constructor, **`this`** is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. So, the `addActionListener(ActionListener)` method is expecting an implemented instance of interface `ActionListener`. When you are passing `this` to `addActionListener` function, which is currently referencing the instance of `PipesUI` wasn't implemented with `ActionListener`.

Implement the `ActionListener` as follows:

```
public class PipesUI extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener
{
 //your code


  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // your code
  }

}
```

But from your code i don't see you have added the `addPipeButton` to any container. Just add the button to your frame `PipesUI` using `add(addPipeButton)` as shown follows:

```
private void addUI(){
    add(addPipeButton);    <--- adding pipe button
    addPipeButton.addActionListener(this);
}
```

This `Jframe.add(addPipeButton)` will add the `addPipeButton` button to the frame's content pane which has `BorderLayout` as default layout manager.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you saw `addActionListener(this)` in another place and decided to use it here. That other place was a completely different context, as `this` was an instance of ActionListner.

Do as follows:

```
addPipeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListner(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //handle `e`
    }
});
```

Edit: You already have `ActionListener` methods in your class. In *this* case, you can use:

```
public class PipesUI extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener {
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution:

```
public class PipesUI extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener{
 //implement the relevant methods
```

Another:

```
private void addUI(){
    addPipeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        //anonymous actionlistener implementation
    };
}
```

and so on and so forth.